# Jenkins fails with Execute shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I have my bash script in `${JENKINS_HOME}/scripts/convertSubt.sh`

My job has build step **Execute shell**:
[image]

However after I run job it fails:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but why do you try to execute a script within a build in your JENKINS_HOME instead of the WORKSPACE of your build?

Comment: 1) Check the script has execution permission. b) Why you run it with sh if it is a bash script? c) Probably (anyway, depending on what your script is doing) it's enough a single line "${JENKINS_HOME}/scripts/convertSubt.sh"

Comment: @gile: Execute permissions are not needed in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message (i.e. the *0:* part) suggests, that there is an error while executing the script.

You could run the script with

```
sh -x convertSubt.sh
```

For the safe side, you could also do a

```
ls -l convertSubt.sh
file convertSubt.sh
```

before you run it.

Comment: I found the problem => mistype in filename :(

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that the script exist with **ls**
2. no need to sh , just ./convertSubs.sh ( make sure you have run permissions)